# maven-gae-plugin, how to package my classes as a JAR?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, jar, maven-gae-plugin

[Apparently](http://www.small-improvements.com/app-engine-performance-tuning/wicket%3apageMapName/wicket-0) its much more efficient to package your own classes and resources as a JAR inside the AppEngine WAR file generateed by the maven-gae-plugin.

How do I do this?  I tried setting `<archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>` in the config for the waven-war-plugin in the pom.xml file but this had no effect.

Comment: Me stupid.  The archiveClasses directive does work.  It leaves an empty class directory which confused me.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Split the code in two project - core and www
2. Let core has only the classes. Set the packaging to jar
3. Let www has only the JSPs, resources, xml and other config files. Make it dependent on the core project. Set the packaging to war.